# 不当と感じるマイナス票を打ち消すための賛成投票はありでしょうか。

Tags: 討議, 投票の仕方

普段は賛成投票をするほどではないが、票がマイナスになっているのはもったいないと思える質問を時々見掛けます。直近の例では以下の質問がそれに当たります。

[【XCODE7】swift2でiOS9の特定の条件の通信でエラーになる。nilが帰ってくる時どうすればいいのか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/16662/7831)

この質問は、2015-09-16 23:00 時点での票は -2 となっています。
人によって当然評価は異なるので、正当だと感じる方も居るかもしれませんが、私の感覚では、特に落ち度がある質問に見えないため、この評価が不当に低く思えます (編集前の初期の版ではやや情報が足りないと感じますが)。
しかし、あまり興味がないジャンルの質問ですので、普段は賛成投票する程ではありません。
このような質問に対して、マイナス票を打ち消す意図で賛成投票を行ってもよいのでしょうか。それとも避けるべきでしょうか。

これに関しては、以下のような異なる考え方があると思っています。

- 行ってもよい：
  評価が低いと、野次馬的な参照はともかく、回答や評価のための参照が減るため、回答や評価を得る機会が減少してしまう。賛成投票はその状況を緩和するのに有効。
- 避けるべき：
  投票は、質問の内容のみによって行うべきで、他人の判断に対する意見表明として行うべきではない。そのような投票はノイズでしかない。

Answer (score 17):

私はそのような賛成投票はありだと思います。

質問の内容をきちんと確認した上でのことですし、投票することで回答がつきやすい状態になることは質問者にとっても（さらには質問サイトとしても）プラスになると考えれば有効な手段だと思います。

Answer (score 12):

> 質問または回答に賛成票を投じることは、その投稿が興味深く、よく研究されており、有用であることをコミュニティに知らせます。反対票を投じることはその逆で、その投稿に間違った情報が含まれていること、調査が不十分であること、または情報を伝えていないことを示します。投稿に投票する人が多いほど、後で訪れる人がその投稿に含まれる情報に確信を持つことができます。賛成票は、時間と労力をかけて良質な投稿を書いた作成者に感謝の気持ちを表すためのとても良い方法であることは言うまでもありません。

という投票の理念からすると、その質問がコミュニティに有益だと判断してプラス票を投じた判断は正しいと思います。

ただ、初版の質問を見る限り漠然としていますし、この内容についてマイナス票が投じることを、 **「不当」と断じることはできない** と思います。マイナス票の結果、編集内容で改善されたのであれば、それはモデレーションのシステムが健全に機能しているということではないでしょうか？

---

ここからは余談ですが、現在の版についても、

- iOS9/XCode7の環境が条件で通信のエラーが発生するのか？
- Swift2の言語仕様としてOptionalをどう扱えばいいのか？
- Cocoa Touchの通信APIで結果がnilが帰ってきた場合どうするのが正しいのか？
- Social IMEのAPIに対して、iOS9で特定のクエリを投げた場合に不正な結果を返すのか？

と、質問の内容が精査しきれておらず、質問者の過去の質問件数など総合的に加味すると、情報を整理する努力を怠っていると感じました。

結果として回答もエラーを回避するための小手先の方法で終わっており、根本的な原因が何なのかについては推測で終わっています。

この質問と答えは、もう少し調査していれば以下のように簡約できたと思います。

**Q:** iOS9の環境でEUC_JPの"夔"をデコードすることができないのはなぜか？
**A:** `NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding`は第3水準以上の漢字を扱うことはできず、"夔"（第4水準漢字）はエンコードもデコードもできない。